# How to Display Label on MDI Form without background Color(Transperent) in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I placed an MDI form in my application . I have given Background image to the MDI Form , And I wants to Display The Label On MDI Form and also wants to add some picture buttons.

So, How should i remove that background color , Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add child controls like a Label to an MDI parent form. It just doesn't work. The only thing that MDI parent forms are designed to contain is child MDI forms.

If you want a background to be visible, you should just use a regular form. The only purpose of MDI is to allow your parent window to act as a container of other sub-windows. This is a fairly obsolete design pattern, one that Microsoft and most other vendors stopped using in their software long ago because it confuses users.

If you drop MDI and use a regular form, you can add whatever Label, Button, and PictureBox controls you want to it. To make them transparent, you can enable their `Transparent` property. This doesn't always work as expected because WinForms doesn't support true transparency, but it sounds like to me that it will work fine for your described use.

Comment: Oh!Is any other way working or not?And what about the panel? if i want to display panel on MDI.

Comment: I have tried to make this with Docking the picture box on MDI , but it is not working...panel  shows their back color as gray...please help me...

Comment: I don't know what else to say that wasn't already covered above. You tried docking a picture box control on an MDI form? That's not going to work. MDI parent forms are designed to contain *only* MDI child controls. Use a regular form instead.